# Count Observation by Groups and ID in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to write a code that count observation based on a condition. I do not know whether it is possible. What i want to achieve is to count only one obeservation in the group instead of adding them together.

This is the dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("P40", "P40", "P40", "P40", "P42", "P42",
                     "P43", "P43", "P43"), Year = c("2013", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014"),
              Meeting = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")),
         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))



ID  Year Meeting
P40 2013     Yes
P40 2013     Yes
P40 2014     Yes
P40 2015     Yes
P42 2013     Yes
P42 2014     Yes
P43 2014     Yes
P43 2014     Yes
P43 2014     Yes
```

The result i want to achieve:

```
ID Year      Count
P40 2013     1
P40 2014     1
P40 2015     1
P42 2013     1
P42 2014     1
P43 2014     1
```

This the code i have so far, this just count all the observation.

```
df %>% group_by(ID, Year) %>% summarise(Count = n())
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you after:

```
count(df %>% distinct(ID, Year), ID, Year, name = 'Count')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  ID    Year  Count
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 P40   2013      1
2 P40   2014      1
3 P40   2015      1
4 P42   2013      1
5 P42   2014      1
6 P43   2014      1
```

Answer (score 3):

We can do a `distinct` on the dataset and then use `count`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   distinct %>% 
   count(ID, Year)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  ID    Year      n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 P40   2013      1
#2 P40   2014      1
#3 P40   2015      1
#4 P42   2013      1
#5 P42   2014      1
#6 P43   2014      1
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df[1:2]))[, .N, .(ID, Year)]
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
subset(as.data.frame(table(unique(df[1:2]))), Freq != 0)
```

Or an option with `cbind`

```
cbind(unique(df[1:2]), n = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you just want to have one observation in each group, wouldn't this be

```
transform(unique(df), count = 1)

#   ID Year Meeting count
#1 P40 2013     Yes     1
#3 P40 2014     Yes     1
#4 P40 2015     Yes     1
#5 P42 2013     Yes     1
#6 P42 2014     Yes     1
#7 P43 2014     Yes     1
```

Or if you want to have check only for selected columns

```
transform(unique(df[1:2]), count = 1)
```